# chrome.windows.getCurrent is not returning the list of opened tabs

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

```
var windows = chrome.windows.getCurrent(
    function(windows){
        try{
            // dont really know why this is null. it should be a list of tabs.
            if(windows.tabs == null) 
        alert(windows.type + " " + windows.id);
        }
        catch(e){
            alert(e);
        }
    });
```

I am using this code to get all the open tabs in the current window. But the window.tabs is always null even though there are tabs open in the current window. Is there something wrong with the concept of current window. 
Could anyone please explain what is it that i am doing wrong. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like the `windows` object that gets passed to your callback doesn't have a `tabs` field. Try this code instead:

```
chrome.windows.getCurrent(function(win)
{
    chrome.tabs.getAllInWindow(win.id, function(tabs)
    {
        // Should output an array of tab objects to your dev console.
        console.debug(tabs);
    });
});
```

Also ensure that you have the `tabs` permission. I also ran this on a background page, so if you're not running it on a background page, you should make sure `chrome.tabs` is available in your context.

Comment: i am running it in the popup and not in the background page. I am new to chrome apis, what do u mean when u say chrome.tabs is available in your context ?

Comment: btw it totally works, but i dont understand what was wrong with my code ?

Comment: Some extensions are basically just content scripts, which is to say they modify the page you're on. Some functionality isn't available with those, and is only available in the background part of the extension. What was wrong with your code is that the `windows` variable you were using never had a `tabs` property (even though it may have made sense to have one); it just wasn't in the API originally.